# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xab in position 0: invalid start byte

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, unicode, python-requests

I want to request to the link, and parse data, but when i get response i can't read.

When i send request from Postman everything is work

I have also body and headers

it's my code ->

```
r=requests.post("Anonymous site",data=json.dumps(d),headers=h2)
print(r.content.decode("utf-8"))
```

`print(r.encoding)` return `utf-8`

I do a lot of searching for a solution on Google but none of them work.
i try change encoding to -> `unicode_escape`, `ISO-8859-1`, `latin1`

Thank you

Comment: Don't change the value of `encoding`. Change the name that you pass to  `decode()`.

Comment: @BoarGules I do exactly that

Comment: If you do *exactly that* with "latin-1", then you can't possibly get the error message you report. Maybe a different error message, but not that one.

Comment: @BoarGules with "latin-1" there are texts similar to "È u XG4‹ íb »"

Comment: Well, now we have got a bit further. That is not an error message. You now have a program thal runs to completion, but that doesn't work as expected. That is a different thing entirely. It looks like the data isn't any of the encodings have guessed. Is it perhaps compressed or encrypted? What are you expecting to get?

Comment: @BoarGules But how i get data with Postman?

Comment: If you are expecting text, print `r.text` not `r.content`.

Comment: @BoarGules with r.text result is similar text "È u XG4‹ íb »"

Comment: Can you make a [mcve]?  If we can make the same call and reproduce the problem, such as seeing your headers and the response's headers, we can help.